# Add path when webpack creates static asset files react, create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react application, which I built with create react app, when I run build it generates the static assets I need and then the index.html file. I am running this on a Ratpack server with gradle. I then use gradle to move these files to my Ratpack directory so I can run it with the Ratpack server. When I move the files I need to add /assets/ onto the url for the JS and CSS file.

For example at the moment it creates the path like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.dab68f70.js">
```

where as I need

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/static/js/main.dab68f70.js">
```

Is it possible to somehow automate this as each time I run my application the files in my ratpack assets are overwritten by the new files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used npm eject, this then exposes all the config files for webpack. From here I edited my webpack config to get my desired paths for my assets.

Answer (score 4):

What about configuring Webpack output publicPath like this?

```
output: {
    ...    
    publicPath: "assets",
}
```

I am using this with Webpack 1.x

The docs can be found here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath

Comment: Where abouts does the config,js file go? I don't have one, I used the create react app

Comment: There is a webpack.config.js file in the root of your project.

Comment: I used create react app, the only thing in the root of my project is build.gradle, package.json and yarn.lock

Comment: You are right, there is no webpack.config.js when you generate the app uding create react app. More info here https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/99

Answer (score 2):

3 Years later......

I had this issue today. And found all the same answers I'm sure you did.

Here is how I fixed it, I went into the index.html file that loads those few files and changed the path manually.

Took about 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"homepage": ".",` in your `package.json` file. It will make the build files with relative path. Bit weird though, but it worked for me.